# Accessing variables of a referenced class library in a Winforms application

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-forms-designer, class-library

I have two projects in my solution explorer:

1. a Windows Forms application with a button.
2. a class library which has methods `a()` and `data()`, which connects to a database and creates a dataset and fills it with tables.

When the button is clicked in the Winforms application, I need to get the rows count. If it is 0, then add value to a label in the Winforms application.

I've already added the reference for the class library in my Winforms project.

Can you please let me know how to access the datatable from the class library and use it to check if its rows count is zero?

Comment: Congrats on what you have achieved so far. What is your question?

Comment: Is there a question here? What is your problem?

Comment: Can you please let me know how to access the datatable from the class library and use it to check if its rows count is zero

Comment: Have the method return the result.

Comment: If you weren't a fairly new user on SO, I'd vote down your question. There is much information missing. First, what variables does your question title refer to? Second, what is the exact role of the methods `a` and `data` you mention? Which one supplies the "rows count", if it's one of them? It's hard to answer your question without more precise information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also have a datalibrary(I call it this as it is a class library only containing data connections) in a C# winforms app. So I am going to explain to you what I have done with mine.

Firstly you have to add the datalibrary under your project references, which I am assuming you have done already.

Next you have to get instances of both your DataAdapters and DataTables.

From here you can work with your datatable instances and get things like the row count etc.

Here is some code you could use in your case:
(Assuming you have a table in your dataLibrary called 'tblCustomer')

```
    dataLibrary.DataAdapters.tblCustomerTableAdapter customerAdapter = new dataLibrary.DataAdapters.tblCustomerTableAdapter(); //this is the instance of the dataAdapter
    dataLibrary.DataSet.tblCustomerDataTable customerTable = new dataLibrary.DataSet.tblCustomerDataTable(); //this is the instance of the dataTable

    int rowsCount = customerTable.Rows.Count;
```

With these instances you can now also get things like the column count in the table etc.

I am giving you this solution from the information that you are giving in your question. If this doesn't work, you will have to give more info on your app.

Answer (score 0):

I guess something like this but comments are right your question lasks info

in class library

```
public DataSet SomeDataSet {get;set;}
```

in winforms application click event

```
var something = new YourClass();

var count = somthing.SomeDataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
```